# SLURM: How to view completed jobs full name?

Tags: slurm

`sacct -n` returns all job's name trimmed for example" `QmefdYEri+`.

[Q] How could I view the complete name of the job, instead of its trimmed version?

--

```
$ sacct -n
1194             run.sh      debug       root          1  COMPLETED      0:0
1194.batch        batch                  root          1  COMPLETED      0:0
1195         run_alper+      debug       root          1  COMPLETED      0:0
1195.batch        batch                  root          1  COMPLETED      0:0
1196         QmefdYEri+      debug       root          1  COMPLETED      0:0
1196.batch        batch                  root          1  COMPLETED      0:0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the `scontrol` command when I am interested in one particular jobid as shown below (output of the command taken from [here](http://www.brightcomputing.com/blog/bid/174099/slurm-101-basic-slurm-usage-for-linux-clusters)).

```
$ scontrol show job 106
JobId=106 Name=slurm-job.sh
UserId=rstober(1001) GroupId=rstober(1001)
Priority=4294901717 Account=(null) QOS=normal
JobState=RUNNING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 ExitCode=0:0
RunTime=00:00:07 TimeLimit=UNLIMITED TimeMin=N/A
SubmitTime=2013-01-26T12:55:02 EligibleTime=2013-01-26T12:55:02
StartTime=2013-01-26T12:55:02 EndTime=Unknown
PreemptTime=None SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0
Partition=defq AllocNode:Sid=atom-head1:3526
ReqNodeList=(null) ExcNodeList=(null)
NodeList=atom01
BatchHost=atom01
NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=2 CPUs/Task=1 ReqS:C:T=*:*:*
MinCPUsNode=1 MinMemoryNode=0 MinTmpDiskNode=0
Features=(null) Gres=(null) Reservation=(null)
Shared=0 Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
Command=/home/rstober/slurm/local/slurm-job.sh
WorkDir=/home/rstober/slurm/local
```

If you want to use `sacct`, you can modify the number of characters that are displayed for any given field as explained in the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html):

> -o, --format Comma separated list of fields. (use "--helpformat" for a list of available fields). NOTE: When using the format option for
>   listing various fields you can put a %NUMBER afterwards to specify how
>   many characters should be printed.
>
> e.g. format=name%30 will print 30 characters of field name right
>   justified. A %-30 will print 30 characters left justified.

Therefore, you can do something like this:

```
sacct --format="JobID,JobName%30,Partition,Account,AllocCPUS,State,ExitCode"
```

if you want the `JobName` row to be 30-characters wide.

Comment: This also return the job-id from its ran name : `sacct --name $jobName.sh -n | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1 | sed -r 's/[.batch]+//g`

Comment: Is there a way to get these details for a completed job? If I use the same command, I get: "slurm_load_jobs error: Invalid job id specified"