# slurm: How can I prevent job's information to be removed?

Tags: slurm, sacct

Using `sacct` I want to obtain information about my completed jobs.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726451/2402577) mentions how could we obtain a job's information.

I have submitted a job name `jobName.sh` which has jobID 176. After 12 hours and new 200 jobs came in, I want to check my job's (jobID=176) information and I obtain `slurm_load_jobs error: Invalid job id specified`.

```
scontrol show job 176
slurm_load_jobs error: Invalid job id specified
```

And following line returns nothing: `sacct --name jobName.sh`

I assume there is a time-limit to keep previously submitted job's information that somehow previous jobs' information has been removed. Is there a limit for that? How could I make that limit very large value in order to prevent them to be deleted?

Please not that `JobRequeue=0` is at slurm.conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [Slurm documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html) mentioned that:

> MinJobAge The minimum age of a completed job before its record is
>   purged from Slurm's active database. Set the values of MaxJobCount and
>   to ensure the slurmctld daemon does not exhaust its memory or other
>   resources. The default value is 300 seconds. A value of zero prevents
>   any job record purging. In order to eliminate some possible race
>   conditions, the minimum non-zero value for MinJobAge recommended is 2.

On my `slurm.conf` file, `MinJobAge` was 300 which is 5 minutes. That's why after 5 minutes each completed job's information was removed. I increased `MinJobAge`'s value in order to prevent the delete operation.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using mySQL to store that data, in your database configuration file *slurmdbd.conf*, you can tune, among others, the purging time. Here you have some examples:

```
PurgeJobAfter=12hours
PurgeJobAfter=1month
PurgeJobAfter=24months
```

If not set (default), then job records are never purged.

More [info](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurmdbd.conf.html).

Comment: By saying *default* means,  `PurgeJobAfter` should be unset right?

Comment: Yes, do not declare it.